# Removal of Duplicates from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have made an anagram below from a words.txt file.

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as read:
    line = read.readlines()

def make_anagram_dict(line):
    word_list = {}

    for word in line:
        word = word.lower()
        key = ''.join(sorted(word))
        if key in word_list and len(word) > 5 and word not in word_list:
            word_list[key].append(word)
        else:
            word_list[key] = [word]

    return word_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_list = make_anagram_dict(line)

    for key, words in word_list.items():
        if len(words) >:
            print('Key value' + ' '*len(key) + '| words')
            print(key + ' '*len(key) + ':' + str(words))
            print('---------------------------------------------')
```

The output I get looks like this (on a random part)

```
Key value | words

hortwy :['worthy\n', 'wrothy\n']
---------------------------------------------
```

But I also get output like this (the duplicate part i am trying to fix)

```
Key value       |     words

eipprz       :['zipper\n', 'zipper\n']
---------------------------------------------
```

the problem is that in the words.txt file, It coins duplicates except for the capital letter at the start:
i.e Zipper and zipper. It therefore creates an anagram of zipper, when it shouldn't. I tried to fix it with the part in bold. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: And please fix the indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Going from `list` to `set` and then back to `list` removes duplicates. To apply this to the values of a dictionary use a comprehension:
`new_dict = {key: list(set(value)) for key, value in old_dict.items()}`

Example

```
my_dict = {"abc": ["abc", "acb", "bac", "bca"],
           "aab": ["aab", "aba", "baa", "aab"]}


new_dict = {key: list(set(value)) for key, value in my_dict.items()}

print(new_dict)
> {'abc': ['abc', 'bca', 'bac', 'acb'], 'aab': ['aba', 'aab', 'baa']}
```

It would in fact by more efficient to just use `set` from the start. Ie:

```
if key in word_list and len(word) > 5 and word not in word_list:
    word_list[key].add(word)
else:
    word_list[key] = {word}
```

If you really need it as a list, you can convert back at the end. I'm not 100% sure whether this method will always preserve order however.